# Enabling MEMORY_OPTIMIZED tables on VCores environment

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I am trying to run some tables in memory (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED )  and I've found [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-in-memory).

I want to work with Vcore environment, and based on the documentation I've expected to be able to work with it. I've just created an empty database and the query below returns 0 (not supported) while I am in

```
SELECT DatabasePropertyEx(DB_Name(), 'IsXTPSupported');
```

[image]

If I change the tier to premium running the query returns 1 though! What am I missing?

### Update

I understand that it says it in not supported in basic and standard, but there is a part that discussing the memory limitation for both Premium and VCore.More importantly the Vcore type is not EDTU base.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's pointed in the documentation, that the In-Memory tables are available only in the premium tier:

> In-Memory technologies are available in all databases in the Premium
>   tier, including databases in Premium elastic pools.

and

> In-Memory OLTP isn't supported in databases in the Standard or Basic
>   tier. In addition, it isn't possible to move a database that has any
>   In-Memory OLTP objects to the Standard or Basic tier.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Please look at the update on my post. They have mentioned vcores and its limitaions on storage and data size part of the document

Comment: @AshkanSirous I suppose the key part is this statement - `Each supported single database pricing tier` where they mean that some of the tiers (the ones which are not premium) are not supported.